# Start Bokeh server without loading scripts/app, but load them when accessing server via browser

Tags: python, server, bokeh

I have multiple scripts that I want to share with my colleagues. These scripts read SQL-databases and generate some plots after calculating correlations and statistical data. In these scripts different variables can be selected to appear in a plot. So my colleagues can choose what plots are generated. Now I would like the have a Bokeh server running (instead of deploying complete python environements), but without preloaded scripts.

Usually, a bokeh server is started with

```
bokeh serve <foo.py>
```

or (when the script is in a directory)

```
bokeh serve <foo>
```

The server is then accessed by:

```
http://localhost:port/foo
```

IMHO, the server starts and loads the given script (incl. variables, data, plots,...) into the memory. Since the scripts executes some queries, it will receive the data that is present when the server is started. The plot can be seen via browser. So far, so good.

Now imagine, the server is running a few weeks after startup without anyone needing it. Eventually, someone wants to have the plots. However, the data in the memory is a few weeks old. So far, not good anymore.

**My question:**

Is there a possibility to start a server without loading any scripts or apps, but to provide a path where the scripts are stored. When the user than accesses the server via

```
http://localhost:port/scriptname
```

the bokeh server should start the corresponding script and getting up-to-date data from the SQL-database. Nice to have would be a clean-up after the user disconnects.

This functionality mirrors somehow the behavior of the shiny-server for R. There, the code is executed, when the user logs onto it.

Comment: There's currently no mechanism to load new applications into a running server. It's potentially possible that one could create a Bokeh application that itself that is responsible for loading other applications from some specified location. In fact this intersects a bit with the "bokeh develop" command that we would like to create. I think this would require exposing a small amount of new API. If you are interested in helping to work on such a feature I encourage you to submit a feature request issue on the GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick reply. It seems that I have to create some kind of update-function that is invoked by clicking a button. Is there a chance to start the bokeh server silently? Currently, there is a python command prompt where all the connects and disconnects are logged.

Comment: `--log-level=critical` should pretty much be silent

Comment: Great, thanks again! As to the primary question: It seems that there is already an [issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3862) at Github. Unfortunately, my skills with server applications are quite limited. I would not be of any help. But I could offer some testing skills and quite some use cases for consideration.

Comment: Is there anything new on this topic? I have seen that bokeh has made some progress...

Comment: There is nothing new as of `0.12.3` (which should be available later today)

Comment: Is this not now possible in `0.12.6` using the `bokeh.client`  `push_session` method?